# MKAnnotation Custom Callout button general action -- how to know which Annotation it's coming from? (iPhone)

Tags: ios5, mapkit, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview, callouts

I'm developing a MapKit app which uses a whole bunch of MKAnnotations to mark locations.  What I want is to put buttons into the callouts which the user can press to perform an action on the selected location.  So far I have seen examples where you can put a specific handler onto each callout, like the apple sample code "MapCallouts".

I want to use one handler for all of the annotation callouts which is general purpose, where I would ideally pass in the MKAnnotation for the active callout.

I've searched and searched in Google to no avail, can anybody give me a pointer or a link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding your own handler method using `addTarget` and then using the `selectedAnnotations` property to figure out which annotation was tapped, I prefer using the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method.

In that delegate method, the annotation tapped is accessed using `view.annotation` and if you've defined a custom annotation class with additional properties, you can do a cast to access them using `(MyAnnotationClass *)view.annotation`.

Comment: That sounds like the exact thing I am looking for, I'll give that a try thanks!